# MS Access (Switch Function)

Tags: ms-access, switch-statement

The following syntax is not working in MS Access SQL view. Basically I have two columns: 1) Rejection Reason  2) Last AP User. And I'm trying to remove from the table anything where there is a word import under rejection reason and renukesha and nagesha under Last AP User column. Code runs perfectly but the rows are not removed from the data table.

Here is my code:

```
 ((Switch([DFM report].[Rejection Reason] like "%Import%" And [Last AP User] 
 ALike "%renukesha%",1,[DFM report].[Rejection Reason] like "%Import%" And 
 [Last AP User] ALike "%nagesha%",1,[DFM report].[Company Code] not like 
 "%Import%",1,True,0))=1)
```

Comment: Where is this switch? You should filter records in the WHERE clause and not with a switch

Comment: This switch is under where clause. I have two other similar switch under where clause which works perfectly. But for some reason this one is not working

Comment: The wildcard character isn't valid for Access - that's a SQL Server wildcard. 
Use  the asterix * instead